# K3d DNS issue with pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns, k3d

With k3d, I am receiving a DNS error when the pod tries to access a URL over the internet.

```
ERROR:
getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN DNS could not be resolved
```

How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your context, OS, version.

For instance, you will see various proxy issue in [`k3d-io/k3d` issue 209](https://github.com/k3d-io/k3d/issues/209)

this could be related to the way k3d creates the docker network.

> Indeed, k3d creates a custom docker network for each cluster and when this happens resolving is done through the docker daemon.
> The requests are actually forwarded to the DNS servers configured in your host's `resolv.conf`. But through a single DNS server (the embedded one of docker).
>
> This means that if your daemon.json is, like mine, not configured to provide extra DNS servers it defaults to 8.8.8.8 which does not resolve any company address for example.
>
> It would be useful to have a custom options to provide to k3d when it starts the cluster and specify the DNS servers there

Which is why there is "[v3/networking: `--network` flag to attach to existing networks](https://github.com/k3d-io/k3d/issues/220)", referring to [Networking](https://k3d.io/v5.3.0/design/networking/).

Before that new flag:

> For those who have the problem, a simple fix is to mount your `/etc/resolve.conf` onto the cluster:
>
> ```
> k3d cluster create --volume /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf
> ```